# Which Control should be used for output directly in page or should I use Response.Write?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, head

I need to output the following... within a User Control.  Currently gets outputted within the .ascx file, but I need to output it in the .ascx.cs file instead to change a control.

The current code in the .ascx file is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=MMG.Global.FileHelper.GetCSSVersion("/scripts/jquery-select2/select2.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=MMG.Global.FileHelper.GetCSSVersion("/styles/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css") %>" />
<link href="<%=MMG.Global.FileHelper.GetCSSVersion("/styles/styles.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="all" />
<link href="<%=MMG.Global.FileHelper.GetCSSVersion("/styles/print.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=MMG.Global.FileHelper.GetCSSVersion("/scripts/jquery-fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css") %>" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.stickyfooter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>-->

<%--<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://tcadops.ca/consumer/adtagtc.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/adtagtc_old.js"></script>

<!-- Smooth Div Scroll Plugin 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.kinetic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/qrs7pfm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
```

But it will need to change to different `<script>` tags depending upon a statement within the .ascx.cs file.  How would I change the above code to something else if using within a .ascx.cs file in an if statement?

I thought about `Response.Write`, but this code has functions also.  Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .ascx file:

```
<% if (someCondition) { %>
    <script>....</script>
<% } 
else { %>
    <script>(Some other script)</script>
<% } %>
```

Then in your code behind (ascx.cs) set the value of `someCondition`

Comment: Thanks, Should I set `someCondition` in the Page_Load event?

Comment: You have an opening bracket, but no closing bracket in the if statement also.  Just noticed this.  Is that correct syntax?

Comment: Wow..way to mix up languages...sorry...all better now (I think)

Comment: Ok, but is it ok to put the someCondition in the `Page_Load` event of the `.ascx.cs` file?  Will that be suitable?

Comment: Yep, that should work just fine.  Code behind is executed before the rendering of the page.

Comment: What if I don't want to create a `CodeBehind` and just want `CodeFile` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading dynamically, keep your code clean and use the conventions provided by ASP.Net. You can do this in either code-behind (or in ASCX if you prefer).

```
ClientScriptManager s = Page.ClientScript;
if(somecondition){
  s.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myscript", "[url to script file]");
}else{
  s.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myscript", "[url to other script file]");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about where it says `"myscript"` what is supposed to be in there exactly??  Anything??  Are these supposed to match where it says `"myscript"` twice?

Comment: It is the `key`. It uniquely identifies your script. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66(v=vs.110).aspx. The key does not have to match, but it is not recommended to use different keys for the same script reference or script block. I think the `key` is useful in cases where script generation occurs frequently during page load. It helps prevent duplication.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  But the URL to the script files will most likely be in .ascx, is that ok in this sense?  Also, can I do `/the/path/MyScript.ascx` in there or do I have to do this: `http://www.mydomain.com/the/path/MyScript.ascx`?

Comment: Also, not sure if this matters, but in the `MasterMain.master` file, there is this bit:  `<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="ScriptControl" Src="~/controls/ScriptControl.ascx" %>`, and `ScriptControl.ascx` is the file with all of the script references noted in my question. Should I just remove this and register it like you have here in that file?  If so, how would that work?

Comment: In regards to `"URL to script file will most likely be in .ascx, is that ok?"`. You could, but that would be, I think, really really awkward. Is there a reason why you need to maintain or reference client script in a ASP.Net User Control? I can understand maintaining the client script in the ascx if locally scoped, but only in that case.

Comment: In regards to '<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg"...', this is a directive that tells your page (master in this case) to use `mmg` when you want to declare an instance of the `User Control`. So, this would allow you to access script from client, but only if you happen to implement a reference to the user control. The directive alone is not enough.

Comment: Yes, it is adding a reference later on down in the code.  Looks like this:  `<mmg:ScriptControl ID="TheScriptControl" runat="server" />`, so would your answer not work in this case?

Comment: Yes...and that is because `TheScriptControl` (instance of `ScriptControl`) is being implemented on the page. Therefore in this case the client script in `ScriptControl.ascx` file will be sent to client.

Comment: So I guess I couldn't implement your answer in that case than...?  Is it possible that since this is being registered in the `Master Page` that it could be used automatically in any other control as well?  If so, than I guess it wouldn't be a good idea to change it to using your implementation.

Comment: My apologies, Solomon, you are correct. If the user control is being registered AND instantiated on the master, then that would be a problem and you would not want to `RegisterClientScriptInclude`.